# Group generated by two elements that is not abelian?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I know that every cyclic group is abelian, but I'm struggling to find a group that is generated by two elements but is not abelian. I'd appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: What's the smallest non-Abelian group?

Comment: What is the isometries group of an equilateral triangle?

Comment: suppose $bab = a^{-1}$

Answer (score 6):

Take any non-abelian group. Take any two non-commuting elements in that group. The subgroup generated by those two elements is non-abelian and generated by two elements.

Comment: So then D2n with order 6, where n=3 would satisfy that? And the elements are just r and s?

Comment: @ZoëS yes that works. By the way, $r,s$ generate $D_{2n}$ so you can just take this group.

Comment: If the downvoter could tell me what they find wrong with this answer, I could actually make it better.